# Find and replace all occurrence of const char* in char*

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm trying to create a function that replaces all occurrence of specific `const char*` in a `char*` string.

Here's my Code:

```
#include <iostream>

void replace(char **bufp, const char *searchStr, const char *replaceStr)
{
    //what should I do here?
}

int main()
{
    char *txt = const_cast<char *>("hello$world$");
    replace(&txt, "$", "**");
    std::cout << "Result: " << txt << '\n';
}
```

The result I get:

```
Result: hello$world$
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The result I want:

```
Result: hello**world**
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Break it down into smaller steps. For example, how would you iterate over all the characters? How would you compare characters? What's the quickest way to determine if a character's in a string?

Comment: Maybe try to think about the problem a bit? I am pretty sure that you can, for example, change one letter in that string, can't you? Let's say you want to replace the `h` in the `hello$world` for `H`, how would you proceed?

Comment: You would be much better making the signature of `replace` be `std::string replace(const char* input, const char* searchStr, const char* replaceStr)`.  `replace` is going to have to allocate a new buffer anyway, and using `std::string` will simplify buffer management.

Comment: That's because you are modifying a read-only memory, use a char array instead of the pointer to the string literal.

Comment: This code smells very bad. What are you trying to achieve in words. The const issue is muddying the waters. Is this a problem that you have been set? Where has the prototype for replace come from?  Is there, or could you set, an upper limit on the length of the string? How are you going to deal with the string getting bigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is already undefined behavior, as you're casting away const, string literals like `"hello$world$"` are usually placed in read-only memory, and any attempt to modify them will likely result in a segfault, you should use `std::string` instead.

With `std::string` your replace function could look like this:

```
void replace(std::string& str, const std::string& find, const std::string& replace)
{
    std::size_t position{};
    while((position = str.find(find)) != std::string::npos){
          str.erase(position,find.size());
          str.insert(position,replace);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need a char* to pass the result string to a function somewhere else, you can use `c_str()` on your `std::string`, which will return a char*. 

You can read more about it here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char*`, not `char*`.

Comment: If you need `char *` you can use `&str[0]`.